# Is it semantically correct to use a foreign key to indicate a range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, semantics

I'm trying to create SQL tables to represent a series of codes used by a third-party API. So far, I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE ApiCode (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ResponseCode char(1) NOT NULL,
    ResponseSubCode char(1) NOT NULL,
    ResponseSubSubCode char(1) NULL,
    MinorCodeRangeId int NULL REFERENCES ApiMinorCodeRange,
    Description nvarchar(500)
)
CREATE TABLE ApiMinorCodeRange (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,

    FromMinorCode char(4) NOT NULL,
    ThruMinorCode char(4) NOT NULL    
)
CREATE TABLE ApiMinorCode (
    Code char(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Description nvarchar(500)
)
```

The problem is, `FromMinorCode` and `ThruMinorCode` can reference codes that don't exist. For example: a range can indicate "5000 - 5ZZZ", but `MinorCode` might only have entries defined for "5000 - 500A". New codes are added every few months, so the `ApiMinorCodeRange` table needs to reference the entire range defined in the specs.

I was planning to create foreign keys anyway and mark them as `NOCHECK`:

```
ALTER TABLE ApiMinorCodeRange ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FromMinorCode FOREIGN KEY ( FromMinorCode ) REFERENCES ApiMinorCode
ALTER TABLE ApiMinorCodeRange NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_FromMinorCode

ALTER TABLE ApiMinorCodeRange ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ThruMinorCode FOREIGN KEY ( ThruMinorCode ) REFERENCES ApiMinorCode
ALTER TABLE ApiMinorCodeRange NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_ThruMinorCode
```

Is this semantically correct?

Will Sql Server's query optimizer be ok with foreign keys that reference an imaginary row?

Should I create a dummy value "5ZZZ - Reserved for future use" instead of setting "NoCheck"?

Comment: I guess it depends on whether you mind having incorrect data in your database.  I would object to invalid data in my database. I would ensure that the valid ranges are enforced fully, somehow.  I would not use NOCHECK.  I'm not sure exactly how I'd do it; I would need more background information on the data.  In the worst case, there'd be one row per minor code (with many rows for each minor code range).  I'm not sure whether a more compact range-based notation can be devised — a lot depends on the DBMS and I'm not an expert on MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to implement a business rule that will apply to codes that you have not yet seen.  There is not necessarily a "right" way to do this.

Does a range relationship have to include valid codes?  I don't see why.  For instance, this [picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8c/Encyclopedia_of_Mathematics,_Complete_Set.jpg) of a set of encyclopedias (remember those?) has ranges on each volume, such as:

- A-B
- C
- Sto-Zyg

I don't assume that "sto" is a valid entry in that volume.  I do assume that "stochastic process" would be in the volume.

Why should your codes be different?  More pertinently in your case, the range in your case could (possibly) be `'5'` to `'5ZZZ'`, even though a `'5'` might not be a valid code.

And, your rules could end up extending beyond mere ranges.  Perhaps some major code has all minor codes that start with "5" and end with "Z".

My conclusion for the ranges is that requiring a foreign key relationship isn't necessary.

That said, there is another problem that you might want to deal with.  What prevents a code from being in multiple ranges?  I suspect that you would need a trigger to enforce this rule.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I was under the impression that a foreign key would be more correct since the fields are related (even if it doesn't correspond to an actual value), but I see your point about the ranges not necessarily being valid codes themselves.

It isn't likely that the codes would ever stop using ranges. The API is provided by a major financial company, so they would be more likely to create a new API altogether rather than dealing with the regulated notifications involved in changing their published specs.